# Прямая ли речь?

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

***«Мама, положи мне 1000 рублей на этот номер, я потом всё объясню»(,) – распространённое мошенническое сообщение.***
Стоит оформлять как прямую речь, с запятой? Или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**«Мама, положи мне 1000 рублей на этот номер, я потом всё объясню» –** распространённое мошенническое сообщение.

Здесь используется так называемое *упрощенное оформление прямой речи*.
Дословное сообщение заключается в кавычки, оно является членом предложения (подлежащим). Тире ствится между подлежащим и сказуемым.